# Rsync mishap .. OS hdd is now full

Tags: rsync

I attempted to use the command:

```
sudo rsync -vaE --progress /Volumes/1-mate /Volumes/Hired-Hand
```

.. to move the contents of one connected drive to another. This was going great until my boot drive filled all the way up (150mb free now).

The problem is that I mistyped the name of the destination.. should have been "HiredHand" NOT "Hired-Hand".

I am clueless where the copied files were placed and need to delete them so that I can use my computer again. Please help!

I am using macOS. Cannot locate any threads anywhere that deal with this issue.. other than someone 3 years ago on stack exchange saying "they found the files" and all is well now for them.

Thank you.

Comment: Aren‘t they in `/Volumes/Hired-Hand`?

Comment: So the problem is that I don't know where rsync created this volume.. somewhere on my main drive. I cannot find a .hired-hand or anything of the sort anywhere. I solved the main problem, only didn't learn much from it all.. I tried cd /Volumes/Hired-Hand and terminal indeed found it.. somewhere. From there, I used the command to list what's in it.. it showed the source disk name as a directory. I used sudo rm -R <directory name> and it deleted the contents and cleared up my space. the "volume" Hired-Hand is somewhere on my root directory unbeknownst to me.. as it isn't and was never physical.

Comment: `Hired-Hand` is just a directory, not a volume. If you removed all its content already you can use `rmdir` to remove it.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. ls -l /Volumes lists it as a Volume under "root"  and "wheel" just the same as my OS HDD. The command "Mount" shows all my physical drives, just none with this name. At this point, its just a bit of a cleanliness thing.. don't want to see it as a volume forever, but since my space is back, there are worse things for a noob to have to deal with. Thank you for the very fast advice, nonetheless.

Comment: `Hired-Hand` is not a volume, it's "just" a directory. Creating a directory in `/Volumes` doesn't magically create volumes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently magically going on within `/Volumes`. So if you use `rsync` or something else to copy data into that folder, it will just do as told. If there is no folder with the target name already it will just create a new one on your main drive.

So

```
sudo rm -rf /Volumes/Hired-Hand
```

should remove the files/folders created by `rsync`. Just make sure you get the name right (and maybe eject the `HiredHand` drive first).

Comment: Thank you for this clarification and for all the collective activity shared here on my plight! Problem solved. For anyone else who might have the same questions as I did here, adding --inplace to the above command in the question, allows me to use rsync to move files without copying them to my OS HDD first, and thereby eliminate using space I don't have in this process.